# must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in redis

Tags: c#, redis

When I save an object, I get the following error :

```
must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.Store<T>(T)


RedisClass.GetInstance().Store(msg); // Error here
RedisClass.GetInstance().Save();
```

As this is a third party's class, I can't edit it. How do I save this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you create a wrapper around the third party object to call its constructor, then store the wrapper?

E.g.

```
public class MyWrapper
{
    public ThirdPartyObject ThirdPartyInstance { get; set; }

    public MyWrapper()
    {
        ThirdPartyInstance = new ThirdPartyObject("Constructors");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by that IBasicPersistenceProvider.Store<T>() has the new() generic constraint. Instead, try using IBasicPersistenceProvider<T>.Store():

```cs
RedisClass.GetInstance().As<ThirdPartyClass>().Store(msg);
```